# Jquery Datatables TypeError undefined error

Tags: jquery, datatables

I have set up previous working Datatables with similar code, but for some reason on this other area of my site it refuses to work, and throws TypeError: g[(d + i)][f] is undefined

Code:

```
<table id="tableSearchResults" class="table table-striped table-hover">
<thead>
 <tr>
  <th>Amenity</th>
  <th>Activity</th>
  <th>Period</th>
  <th>Booked by</th>
  <th>Unit</th>
  <th>Reference</th>
  <th>Status</th>
  <th class="no-sort"></th>
 <tr>
</thead><tbody></tbody></table>


   var dataSet = [["Ballroom", "lalalala", "2/6/2017<br />10:00 AM - 12:30 PM", "Internal booking", "N/A", "", "<a href='#' id='payment43' data-toggle='popover' data-html='true' data-content='<b>Received By</b><br />Robert Benedetto<br />2/6/2017 2:59:24 PM'>PAID</a>", "<a href='amenity_booking.aspx?d=43&bb=0' onclick='return confirm(&quotAre you sure you want to permanently delete this booking?&quot);'><i class='fa fa-trash'></i></a>"], ["Ballroom", "Testing", "8/29/2017<br />9:00 AM - 9:30 AM", "HoangTest TranTest", "<a href='unit_info.aspx?uid=7005'>1S Narra, 1408</a>", "", "<span class='label label-danger'>PENDING</span>", "<a href='amenity_booking.aspx?d=44&bb=1' onclick='return confirm(&quotAre you sure you want to permanently delete this booking?&quot);'><i class='fa fa-trash'></i></a>"]];

    $("#tableSearchResults").DataTable({
        data: dataSet,
        "deferRender": true,
        "lengthMenu": [[50, 100, 150, 200, 250, -1], [50, 100, 150, 200, 250, "All"]],
        "iDisplayLength": 100,
        "order": [],
        "columnDefs": [{ "targets": 'no-sort', "orderable": false }, { "searchable": false, "targets": [2, 6, 7] }]
    });
```

Can anyone spot anything that is off? I sure can't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't close `tr` element, it should be  `</tr>` not `<tr>`.

Comment: You are right, thanks, but it doesnt solve it though.

Comment: It did solve it. Had removed # from the ID name to experiment, forgot to add it back. Thanks!

Comment: your code works well, no idea why you said it did not solve your issue https://jsfiddle.net/r5p1ovdq/

Comment: oh man, I wasted my 2 hours on this silly mistake. :(